# Stored Procedure for insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, syntax-error, sql-insert

I am taking a `datatable` as parameter in my stored procedure and I am trying to insert a few of its column in one of the database tables but I don't know the correct syntax.

This is what I have tried

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertInvoice]
    @tblInvoice [TypeExcel] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT into Invoice(InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, CustomerName,[Subject], Reference)
    VALUES (SELECT Template, Invoice_No, InvoiceDate, Cust_Name,[Subject], Reference FROM @tblInvoice)
END
```

Please guide me how can I correctly insert values in my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the form of insert that takes a select rather than a values:

```
insert into theTable (col1, col2, ...)
select col1, col2, ...
from ...
where...
```

All the features of a select are available (column aliases, grouping, joins, sub queries, ...).

Comment: That doesnt' work. Using that form of an insert still doesn't let you use a variable to specify the table name.

Comment: @Guffa It does. [Data table parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) can be used directly in the from clause.

Comment: I see, i assumed that it was a table name.